# How to store URL in a table field

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am with a new requirement in PHP in which I am trying to store in a field of a table the URL to which the user enters once he enters with their respective credentials. The way I am trying to get the URL in which the user enters is the following:

```
  $host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
  $url= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  echo "http://" . $host . $url;
```

With the previous sentence I have managed to obtain the URL to which the user enters, now what I require is to store this in the field that I have created in my table.

For the user's entry I have prepared a stored procedure where it validates their credentials `username` and in `password` addition to storing the time of last access. The procedure is the next:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateCredentials]
    @USER VARCHAR(20),
    @PASS VARCHAR(20)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @LASTACCESS DATETIME
    
    SELECT @LASTACCESS = 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN U.LASTACCESS = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN GETDATE()
                                ELSE U.LASTACCESS
                            END
    FROM USUARIOS U
    WHERE 
        U.USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

        
    UPDATE USUARIOS
        SET LASTACCESS = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT @LASTACCESS ACCESO, INSERTED.*      
        WHERE 
            USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            
END
```

The structure of my table `USUARIOS` is as follows, where the column `URL` is where I want to store the respective URL that the user enters.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USUARIOS](
    [NOMBRE] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [PASSWORD] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [LASTACCESS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [USUARIO] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [TIPOUSUARIO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
)
```

From PHP I have the following call to the stored procedure and the respective validations of the `USER` and `PASS`:

```
 $USER = $_POST['username'];
        $PASS = $_POST['password'];
        $query = array();
        include './db/connect.php';
        $sql = "{call ValidateCredentials(?,?)}";
        $params = array($USER ,$PASS);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
        if ( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }   
        session_start();
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $record = array(
                "usuario"   => utf8_encode($row['USUARIO']),
                "nombre"    => utf8_encode($row['NOMBRE']),
                "ultimoacceso" => $row['ACCESO'],
                "tipoproveedor" => $row['TIPOUSUARIO'],                   
                );
                    
            array_push($query, $record);                
        }
        $size = sizeof($query);
        if($size != 0){
            $_SESSION["acceso"] = time();               
        }

        $_SESSION['validacion'] = $query;
        
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['validacion']);
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

I appreciate who can support me in being able to store the URL in the field that I mentioned above.

**Update 1:**

I have tried the following, first I have passed the parameter of the url when I call the process `UPDATE USUARIOS SET URL= @url` as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateCredentials]
    @USER VARCHAR(20),
    @PASS VARCHAR(20),
    @URL VARCHAR(max)
 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @LASTACCESS DATETIME
    
    SELECT @LASTACCESS = 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN U.LASTACCESS = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN GETDATE()
                                ELSE U.LASTACCESS
                            END
    FROM USUARIOS U
    WHERE 
        U.USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

        
    UPDATE USUARIOS
        SET LASTACCESS = GETDATE(),
            URL=@URL
    OUTPUT @LASTACCESS ACCESO, INSERTED.*      
        WHERE 
            USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            
END
```

And then in addition to this I have added a third parameter in the call of the stored procedure from PHP as follows:

```
$sql = "{call ValidateCredentials(?,?,?)}";
```

At the moment of wanting to log in with the respective credentials I have obtained the following as an error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07002
            [SQLSTATE] => 07002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
        )

)
```

I don't know if something else is needed in my stored procedure or something else from my PHP code

Comment: Side note: `... WHEN U.LASTACCESS = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' ...` -- Don't use such nonsense values as placeholders. Use `NULL` if a date is unknown.

Comment: @stickybit 
Thanks for the note, I will take it into account for the next version, any other suggestions regarding the initial question?

Comment: Another side note, you should not be passing, storing or comparing passwords; Your application should *hash* the user's password, only the *hashed value* should be stored and you validate by comparing the hashed password to the stored hashed value.

Comment: Why can't you just pass it through as another parameter?

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the note, I already had it contemplated for my next version, any suggestions regarding the initial question?

Comment: @Charlieface I have done what you told me to pass it as a parameter but I got an error when entering with my credentials, check my last update so that you understand it better

Comment: @user11804298, you need to pass the actual value of the new 3rd parameter: `$params = array($USER ,$PASS, $HOST);`, where `$HOST  = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`.